# JSONDecodeError Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) with empty array response

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm making a GET request using requests package in Python 3.6 and I'm getting the above error. I tried the same request on curl and got this as a response:

```
{
  "value": []
}
```

Would an empty response like this be causing the error?

Comment: `json.loads('{"value": []}')` works as expected, so there must be something you're not showing us.

Comment: Show us the actual python code you're using to make the request.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to json

```
import json
response = requests.get(url)
json.loads((response.content).decode('utf-8'))
```